# relationship that "inherit" another (1:N) relationship

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures, game-engine, one-to-many

I want a data-structure that supports these specific 1:N relations :-
1#. `Human` **raise** 0-N `Human`
2#. `Human` **has** 0-N `Dog`
3#. `Human` **cultivate** 0-N `Tree`
4#. `Dog` **is a house of** 0-N `Parasites`.

[image]

**Note:**
- State in these relations are all temporary e.g. `Human1` may **raise** `Human2`, but after a year, `Human1` may abandon `Human2`.
- All objects are inherited from `BaseObject` and has unique int ID.

In all of the above relation, I want to be able to support these features :-
F1. add relation e.g. `human_dog->addRelation(Human* a,Dog* b)`
F2. remove relation e.g. `human_dog->removeRelation(Human* a,Dog* b)`
F3. query all children e.g. `human_dog->getAllChildren(Human*)`
F4. query all parent e.g. `human_dog->getAllParents(Dog*)`
F5. check whether a parent has >=1 child
F6. check whether a child has >=1 parent
F7. remove all children for a parent
F8. remove all parent for a child

This can be implemented by `std::unordered_map` or something more customized quite easily.

### Here comes the hard part

I want to mark relation 1#,2#,3# (i.e. all solid lines) as **Feed**.
It has to support feature F3-F8 in an ***aggregating*** style.

For example :-

- `feed->getAllChildren(BaseObject* b)`  :
  If `b` is human, it must return all children of **raise**,**has** and **cultivate** of the `b`.
- `feed->removeAllParent(BaseObject* b)` :
  If `b` is a dog, it will effect like `cultivate->removeAllParent(b)`.

In summary, I want to be able to easily inject such ***aggregation***.
Ex. It is useful to call :-

```
void BaseObject::declareForFreedom(){
    feed->removeAllParent(this);
}
```

The above example shows only 4 relations and 1 level of indirection.
In my real case, there are 8-10 relations and 3-4 levels of such inherit/indirection.

### Question

What is a data-structure/design-pattern that suitable for this case?

I currently create a custom 1:N relation for 1#-4#, and hard-code every **feed**'s function.   It is tedious.
I have banged by head for a few months, but not found any implementation that look elegant.

### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f2decd7a8d96e3c

Basic type:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
enum class Type{
    HUMAN,DOG,TREE,PARASITE,ERROR
}; //for simplicity
class BaseObject{public: Type type=Type::ERROR; };
class Human : public BaseObject{
    public: Human(){ type=Type::HUMAN; }    
};
class Dog : public BaseObject{
    public: Dog(){ type=Type::DOG; }    
};
class Tree : public BaseObject{
    public: Tree(){ type=Type::TREE; }    
};
class Parasite : public BaseObject{
    public: Parasite(){ type=Type::PARASITE; }    
};
```

Basic 1:N map

```
template<class A,class B> class MapSimple{
    std::multimap<A*, B*> aToB;
    std::multimap<B*, A*> bToA;
    public: void addRelation(A* b1,B* b2){
        aToB.insert ( std::pair<A*,B*>(b1,b2) );   
        bToA.insert ( std::pair<B*,A*>(b2,b1) );   
    }
    public: std::vector<B*> queryAllChildren(A* b1){
        auto ret = aToB.equal_range(b1);
        auto result=std::vector<B*>();
        for (auto it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it){
            result.push_back(it->second);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public: void removeAllParent(B* b){
        if(bToA.count(b)==0)return;
        A* a=bToA.find(b)->second;
        bToA.erase(b);
        auto iterpair = aToB.equal_range(a);
        auto it = iterpair.first;
        for (; it != iterpair.second; ++it) {
            if (it->second == b) { 
                aToB.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //.. other functions 
};
```

Here is the database instance and the aggregation :-

```
MapSimple<Human,Human> raise;
MapSimple<Human,Dog> has;
MapSimple<Human,Tree> cultivate;
MapSimple<Dog,Parasite> isHouseOf;
class Feed{
    public: void removeAllParent(BaseObject* b1){
        if(b1->type==Type::HUMAN){
            raise.removeAllParent(static_cast<Human*>(b1));
        } 
        if(b1->type==Type::DOG){
            has.removeAllParent(static_cast<Dog*>(b1));
        }
        //.... some other condition (I have to hard code them - tedious) ...
    }
    //other function 
};
Feed feed;
```

Usage

```
int main(){
    Human h1;
    Dog d1,d2;

    has.addRelation(&h1,&d1);
    has.addRelation(&h1,&d2);
    auto result=has.queryAllChildren(&h1);
    std::cout<<result.size(); //print 2
    feed.removeAllParent(&d1);
    result=has.queryAllChildren(&h1);
    std::cout<<result.size(); //print 1
}
```

Comment: Why basic classes/structs and vectors does not suit your problem?

Comment: @Incomputable I don't know a way to inject "dependency/aggragation" between 2 relations elegantly.  I already use class, array, vector.  I believe I face a higher-level (aka big picture) problem.  I can make it works, but it is very dirty.

Comment: Your description is hard to follow, but the actual problem does not seem so difficult. Aren't you over-thinking it? Can you write some minimal example code, so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JHBonarius  Thank, I will try.  It will take sometimes.

Comment: @JHBonarius I just finish MCVE.  Thank.

Comment: I would put std::vector&lt;BaseObject*&gt; children/parents in BaseObject class, then also an add/remove (all) parent/child method. Then you can override them in the sub classes if you need to add certain restrictions.

Comment: @super It is an interesting idea and useful, thank.  Some disadvantages : 1. virtual cost (probably not more expensive than my `if(type)` anyway)  2. tight coupling between relation-functionality and object.

Comment: To avoid the coupling you can add another layer of a few relation classes that in turn inherits from BaseObject. Then human/dog can inherit from the relation classes.

Comment: @super  Human--⊳SomeRelationBehavior-⊳BaseObject ?  I think that is still a tight coupling, because Human will has some specific relation's behavior.    The feature of relation are merged into Human.  As a result, I can't use Human as an independent class anymore i.e. hard to reuse in other projects that doesn't has certain relations.   Anyway, I still think your approach is interesting. Thank.

Comment: To me it seems you are over-optimizing things. Why not make a `Human`, `Dog` etc class that contain methods for `addParent`, `addChild`, `removeAllParents` etc. methods? Much more readable and maintainable. Now you have to do all this condition checking, where you do basically the same. I don't get why you want to put every relation into one list....

Comment: That would depend on how you model it. Have a look at mixins as a concept. It uses inheritance but would keep human and it's relation aspects separate.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the straight-forward implementation?

E.g.:
BaseObject.hpp

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using prtVector = std::vector<T*>;

class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const = 0;
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChilderen() const = 0;
    virtual void removeAllParents() = 0;
    virtual void removeAllChildren() = 0;
};
```

Human.hpp

```
#include "BaseObject.hpp"
#include "Tree.hpp"
#include "Dog.hpp"
class Tree;
class Dog;

class Human : public BaseObject {
public:
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override;
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override;

    void removeAllParents() override;
    void removeAllChildren() override ;

    friend class Dog;
    friend class Tree;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend void addRelation(A* a, B* b);
private:
    void addParent(Human* const);
    void removeParent(Human const* const);
    void addChild(Human* const);
    void removeChild(Human const* const);
    void addChild(Tree* const);
    void removeChild(Tree const* const);
    void addChild(Dog* const);
    void removeChild(Dog const* const);
private:
    prtVector<Human> parents;
    prtVector<Human> children;
    prtVector<Tree> plants;
    prtVector<Dog> pets;
};
```

Human.cpp

```
#include "Human.hpp"

prtVector<BaseObject> Human::getAllParents() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(parents), std::cend(parents));
    return result;
}

prtVector<BaseObject> Human::getAllChildren() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(children), std::cend(children));
    result.insert(std::end(result), std::cbegin(pets), std::cend(pets));
    result.insert(std::end(result), std::cbegin(plants), std::cend(plants));
    return result;
}

void Human::removeAllParents() {
    for (auto parent : parents) { parent->removeChild(this); }
    parents.clear();
}

void Human::removeAllChildren() {
    for (auto child : children) { child->removeParent(this); } children.clear();
    for (auto pet : pets) { pet->removeParent(this); } pets.clear();
    for (auto plant : plants) { plant->removeParent(this); } plants.clear();
}

void Human::addParent(Human* const parent) { parents.push_back(parent); }

#include <algorithm>
void Human::removeParent(Human const* const parent) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parents), std::cend(parents), parent);
    if (it != std::cend(parents)) parents.erase(it);
}
void Human::addChild(Human* const child) { children.push_back(child); }
```

etc, etc...

Same for other types....

main.cpp

```
#include "Human.hpp"
#include "Dog.hpp"

template<class A, class B>
void addRelation(A* a, B* b)
{
    a->addChild(b);
    b->addParent(a);
}

template<class A>
prtVector<BaseObject> queryAllChildren(A* obj)
{
    return obj->getAllChilderen();
}

template<class A>
void removeAllParents(A* obj)
{
    obj->removeAllParents();
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Dog d1, d2;

    addRelation(&h1, &d1);
    addRelation(&h1, &d2);
    auto result = queryAllChildren(&h1);
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 2
    removeAllParents(&d1);
    result = queryAllChildren(&h1);
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 1

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

IMHO this gives readable and maintainable code. Can probably be optimized somewhat. But at least the relationships are very clear from the code.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of duplicated code :(  , but I agree that it is very readable and clear.  Thank.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

Better code was suggested by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180093/6717178). C++17 style:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual ~BaseObject() = default;
    virtual std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllParents() const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllChildren() const = 0;
    virtual void removeAllParents() = 0;
    virtual void removeAllChildren() = 0;
};

template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename... ParentTags,
         typename... ChildTags>
class Obj<std::tuple<ParentTags...>, std::tuple<ChildTags...>> : public BaseObject
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<typename ParentTags::obj_type*>...> parents;
    std::tuple<std::vector<typename ChildTags::obj_type*>...> children;

public:

    template <typename T>
    void addParent(T* parent) { std::get<std::vector<T*>>(parents).push_back(parent); }

    template <typename T>
    void removeParent(const T* parent) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T*>>(parents);
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), parent);
        if (it != std::cend(v)) { v.erase(it); }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void addChild(T* child) { std::get<std::vector<T*>>(children).push_back(child); }

    template <typename T>
    void removeChild(const T* child) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T*>>(children);
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), child);
        if (it != std::cend(v)) { v.erase(it); }
    }

    std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllParents() const override {
        std::vector<BaseObject*> res;

        std::apply([&](auto&... v){ (res.insert(res.end(), v.begin(), v.end()), ...); },
                   parents);
        return res;
    }
    std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllChildren() const override {
        std::vector<BaseObject*> res;

        std::apply([&](auto&... v){ (res.insert(res.end(), v.begin(), v.end()), ...); },
                   children);
        return res;
    }

    void removeAllParents() override {
        std::apply(
            [this](auto&... v)
            {
                [[maybe_unused]] auto clean = [this](auto& v) {
                    for (auto* parent : v) {
                        parent->removeChild(this);
                    }
                    v.clear();
                };
                (clean(v), ...);
            },
            parents);
    }

    void removeAllChildren() override {
        std::apply(
            [this](auto&... v)
            {
                [[maybe_unused]] auto clean = [this](auto& v) {
                    for (auto* child : v) {
                        child->removeParent(this);
                    }
                    v.clear();
                };
                ( clean(v), ...);
            },
            children);
    }
};

struct Human_tag;
struct Tree_tag;
struct Dog_tag;
struct Parasite_tag;

using Human = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<Parasite_tag>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;

struct Human_tag { using obj_type = Human; };
struct Tree_tag { using obj_type = Tree; };
struct Dog_tag { using obj_type = Dog; };
struct Parasite_tag { using obj_type = Parasite; };

template<class A, class B>
void addRelation(A* a, B* b)
{
    a->addChild(b);
    b->addParent(a);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Dog d1, d2;

    addRelation(&h1, &d1);
    addRelation(&h1, &d2);
    auto result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 2
    d1.removeAllParents();
    result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 1
}
```

## Old code: (my attempt)

OK, since you did not want duplicated code, I've been using this project as my first experience with metaprogramming/variadic templating. So this is what I got:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
using prtVector = std::vector<T*>;

// Interface, as required by assignment
class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual ~BaseObject() {}
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const = 0;
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const = 0;
    virtual void removeAllParents() = 0;
    virtual void removeAllChildren() = 0;
};

// base prototype
template<typename TOwnTag, typename TParentTagsTuple, typename TChildTagsTuple>
class Obj;

// Parent-type deduction
template<typename TOwnTag, typename TParentTag, typename... TParentTags, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTag, TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    // local types
    using TOwn = typename TOwnTag::obj_type;
    using TParent = typename TParentTag::obj_type;
    // container
    prtVector<TParent> parentsPtrs;
    //befriend types
    friend class Obj;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend void addRelation(A* const a, B* const b);
protected:
    // prevent base function hiding with 'using'-declaration
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::addParent;
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeParent;
    // add and remove element functions
    void addParent(TParent* const parentPtr) { parentsPtrs.push_back(parentPtr); }
    void removeParent(TParent const* const parentPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs), parentPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(parentsPtrs)) parentsPtrs.erase(it);
    }
public:
    virtual ~Obj() {}
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        auto result = Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllParents();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllParents();
        for (auto&& parent : parentsPtrs) parent->removeChild(reinterpret_cast<TOwn* const>(this));
    }
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
    }
};

// Child-type deduction
template<typename TOwnTag, typename TChildTag, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTag, TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    // local types
    using TOwn = typename TOwnTag::obj_type;
    using TChild = typename TChildTag::obj_type;
    // container
    prtVector<TChild> childrenPtrs;
    //befriend types
    friend class Obj;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend void addRelation(A* const a, B* const b);
protected:
    // empty functions required for 'using'-declaration
    void addParent() {}
    void removeParent() {}
    // prevent base function hiding with 'using'-declaration
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::addChild;
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeChild;
    // add and remove element functions
    void addChild(TChild* const childPtr) { childrenPtrs.push_back(childPtr); }
    void removeChild(TChild const* const childPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs), childPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(childrenPtrs)) childrenPtrs.erase(it);
    }
public:
    virtual ~Obj() {}
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllParents();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        auto result = Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
        for (auto&& child : childrenPtrs) child->removeParent(reinterpret_cast<TOwn* const>(this));
    }
};

// terminator
template<typename TOwnTag>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>> : public BaseObject {
protected:
    // empty functions required for 'using'-declaration
    void addChild() {}
    void removeChild() {}
    void addParent() {}
    void removeParent() {}
public:
    virtual ~Obj() {}
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {}
};

//prototype class tags
struct Human_tag;
struct Tree_tag;
struct Dog_tag;
struct Parasite_tag;
//define class types
using Human = Obj<Human_tag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<Tree_tag, std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<Dog_tag, std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<Parasite_tag>>;
using Parasite = Obj<Parasite_tag, std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
//couple tags to classes
struct Human_tag { using obj_type = Human; };
struct Tree_tag { using obj_type = Tree; };
struct Dog_tag { using obj_type = Dog; };
struct Parasite_tag { using obj_type = Parasite; };

//(befriend)helper function
// maybe could do somehting with std::enable_if
// i.e. "enable if type B is in child tuple of A and
//  type A is in parent tuple of B"
// that way the parser will already detect a relation is not possible
template<class A, class B>
void addRelation(A* const a, B* const b)
{
    a->addChild(b);
    b->addParent(a);
}

// now for some testing
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Dog d1, d2;
    Parasite p1;

    addRelation(&h1, &d1);
    addRelation(&h1, &d2);
    addRelation(&d1, &p1);
    //addRelation(&h1, &p1); // compiler error
    auto result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 2
    d1.removeAllParents();
    result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 1

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Please ask questions about anything that is unclear, because I've been learning so much new stuff over the past 24 hours, that I don't know where to begin with my explanation.