# Conflictions declaration / redefinition: different basic types

Tags: c++, templates, parent-child

I'm trying to use a variadic templated class to make a structure of parent-child relationships.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename... TParents, typename... TChildren>
class Obj<std::tuple<TParents...>, std::tuple<TChildren...>> {
private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TParents...>>> parentsVectors;
    std::tuple<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TChildren...>>> childrenVectors;
};


using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>>;

using Human = Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree, Dog>>;
using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<Human>, std::tuple<Parasite>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<Dog>, std::tuple<>>;

int main() {}
```

This gives me this kind of error in MSVS2017:

> error C2371: 'Tree': redefinition; different basic types

And this in GCC:

> error: conflicting declaration

I've been looking all over the web on how to fix this, but haven't found it yet. Is this fixable?

## edit:

What I *really* am trying to do is to use metaprogramming to prevent me to write a lot of duplicate code, as I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153193/6717178)

## edit2:

Ok, let's expand. The relationship is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51149076/6717178)

I've been writing the `Human` `Dog`, etc classes like

Human.hpp

```
#include "BaseObject.hpp"
#include "Tree.hpp"
#include "Dog.hpp"
class Tree;
class Dog;

class Human : public BaseObject {
public:
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override;
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override;

    void removeAllParents() override;
    void removeAllChildren() override ;

    friend class Dog;
    friend class Tree;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend void addRelation(A* a, B* b);
private:
    void addParent(Human* const);
    void removeParent(Human const* const);
    void addChild(Human* const);
    void removeChild(Human const* const);
    void addChild(Tree* const);
    void removeChild(Tree const* const);
    void addChild(Dog* const);
    void removeChild(Dog const* const);
private:
    prtVector<Human> parents;
    prtVector<Human> children;
    prtVector<Tree> plants;
    prtVector<Dog> pets;
};
```

Human.cpp

```
#include "Human.hpp"

prtVector<BaseObject> Human::getAllParents() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(parents), std::cend(parents));
    return result;
}

prtVector<BaseObject> Human::getAllChildren() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(children), std::cend(children));
    result.insert(std::end(result), std::cbegin(pets), std::cend(pets));
    result.insert(std::end(result), std::cbegin(plants), std::cend(plants));
    return result;
}

void Human::removeAllParents() {
    for (auto parent : parents) { parent->removeChild(this); }
    parents.clear();
}

void Human::removeAllChildren() {
    for (auto child : children) { child->removeParent(this); } children.clear();
    for (auto pet : pets) { pet->removeParent(this); } pets.clear();
    for (auto plant : plants) { plant->removeParent(this); } plants.clear();
}

void Human::addParent(Human* const parent) { parents.push_back(parent); }

#include <algorithm>
void Human::removeParent(Human const* const parent) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parents), std::cend(parents), parent);
    if (it != std::cend(parents)) parents.erase(it);
}
void Human::addChild(Human* const child) { children.push_back(child); }

void Human::removeChild(Human const* const child) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(children), std::cend(children), child);
    if (it != std::cend(children)) children.erase(it);
}
void Human::addChild(Dog* const pet) { pets.push_back(pet); }

void Human::removeChild(Dog const* const pet) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(pets), std::cend(pets), pet);
    if (it != std::cend(pets)) pets.erase(it);
}
void Human::addChild(Tree* const plant) { plants.push_back(plant); }

void Human::removeChild(Tree const* const plant) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(plants), std::cend(plants), plant);
    if (it != std::cend(plants)) plants.erase(it);
}
```

Same for `Dog`:Dog.hpp

```
#include "BaseObject.hpp"
#include "Human.hpp"
#include "Parasite.hpp"
class Human;
class Parasite;

class Dog : public BaseObject {
public:
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override;
    prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override;

    void removeAllParents() override;
    void removeAllChildren() override;

    friend class Human;
    friend class Parasite;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend void addRelation(A* a, B* b);
private:
    void addParent(Human* const);
    void removeParent(Human const* const);
    void addChild(Parasite* const);
    void removeChild(Parasite const* const);
private:
    prtVector<Human> owners;
    prtVector<Parasite> parasites;
};
```

Dog.cpp

```
#include "Dog.hpp"

prtVector<BaseObject> Dog::getAllParents() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(owners), std::cend(owners));
    return result;
}

prtVector<BaseObject> Dog::getAllChildren() const {
    prtVector<BaseObject> result(std::cbegin(parasites), std::cend(parasites));
    return result;
}

void Dog::removeAllParents() {
    for (auto owner : owners) { owner->removeChild(this); }
    owners.clear();
}

void Dog::removeAllChildren() {
    for (auto parasite : parasites) { parasite->removeParent(this); }
    parasites.clear();
}

void Dog::addParent(Human* const owner) { owners.push_back(owner); }

#include <algorithm>
void Dog::removeParent(Human const* const owner) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(owners), std::cend(owners), owner);
    if (it != std::cend(owners)) owners.erase(it);
}

void Dog::addChild(Parasite* const parasite) { parasites.push_back(parasite); }

void Dog::removeChild(Parasite const* const parasite) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parasites), std::cend(parasites), parasite);
    if (it != std::cend(parasites)) parasites.erase(it);
}
```

And so on for `Tree` and `Parasite`.
As you can see, there is a lot of duplicate code in there! I was thinking that metaprogramming should be able to help me there: generating functions for specific types passed as variadic template arguments.

Comment: Wow, -1 in less then 30 seconds without any comment on why. *edit* aaaand it's gone...

Comment: I'm kind of struggling to imagine how you've painted yourself in a corner where you need to forward-declare a type alias.

Comment: You have `class Tree;` and `using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human>, std::tuple<>>;`.  Both those things can't have the same name.  Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks. But its not a typo, because I cannot fix it by changing `class Tree;` into `using Tree;`

Comment: @NathanOliver, seems like a misconception about the difference between type aliases and actual types. Not really a typo.

Comment: This code actually suffers from infinite recursion in tuples. `std::tuple<Human>` will need `std::tuple<Tree, Dog>` which will need `std::tuple<Human>` again and so on

Comment: Retracted the vote.  Looks like you might need another level of indirection to solve this but what it should be I have no idea.

Comment: I've modified the question, removing the class idea. Yes: those are different types. Still same errors though.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Rakete1111 just edited that into the question a moment ago

Comment: @JHBonarius You're not saying what code you are trying to de-duplicate.

Comment: What kind of parent-child relationships could exist between `Dog` `Human` and `Parasite`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 expanded again

Comment: @VTT that's in the original question. `Human` is parent to `Dog` and `Tree`. `Parasite` is child of `Dog`. Parents and children are aware of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to accomplish, and I believe you can get there using tag types:

```
template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename TParents, typename TChildren>
class Obj<std::tuple<TParents>, std::tuple<TChildren>> {};

struct Human_tag {};
struct Tree_tag {};
struct Dog_tag {};
struct Parasite_tag {};

using Human = Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<Parasite_tag>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
```

You'll most likely hit some other recursive mess down the line though.

**Edit:** expanding the code to show how to map from the tag back to the types:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename... TParents, typename... TChildren>
class Obj<std::tuple<TParents...>, std::tuple<TChildren...>> {
public:
  std::tuple<std::vector<typename TParents::obj_type*>...> parents_;
  std::tuple<std::vector<typename TChildren::obj_type*>...> children_;
};

struct Human_tag;
struct Tree_tag;
struct Dog_tag;
struct Parasite_tag;

using Human = Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<Parasite_tag>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;

struct Human_tag {
    using obj_type = Human;
};
struct Tree_tag {
    using obj_type = Tree;
};
struct Dog_tag {
    using obj_type = Dog;
};
struct Parasite_tag {
    using obj_type = Parasite;
};

void foo() {
    Tree t;
    Human h;

    std::get<0>(t.parents_).emplace_back(&h);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that would solve the error. However, it would not solve my problem. For what I did up to now, I for instance need `Human` to have a `std::vector` of `Tree*`, not `Tree_tag*`.

Comment: @JHBonarius There is no need for any of these type aliases for Human to have a `std::vector` of `Tree` types.

Comment: @VTT I'm not following. Could you elaborate? In my idea I need to pass `Tree` as template parameter to `Obj` for it to be aware of `Tree`??

Comment: @JHBonarius This is quickly going down the rabbit hole, but here's an example of how to extend this to have your vectors: https://godbolt.org/g/3SXoic

Comment: @Frank That's the kind of info I'm actually looking for. I've actually been programming C++ for 20 years now. But am totally not up-to-date with new techniques. Using this question to get me further.

Comment: @JHBonarius There is no need for templates here. [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kkJuXYMzlBsSlnaf)

Comment: It needs to be notted that @VTT's example is only valid as presented in C++17 and above, as it depends on N4510.

Comment: @VTT yes, but then I'm back with [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153193/6717178) with a lot of duplicate code. Which I want to reduce. Should I just open a new question: "how to reduce duplicate code with metaptrogramming"?

Comment: @Frank: you showed me the path. If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly except it.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not sure what you are referring to. I've already updated the answer with the contents of the godbolt link. Maybe you just need to refresh the page?

Comment: @Frank I've finished my work: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173085/6717178). Thanks for the help. Things can be improved, as there are some bugs, but I'm rather happy about the result.