# getting original type of this object

Tags: c++, parent-child, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm trying to use metaprogramming to prevent duplicate code in a parent-child structure. I got it working up to a certain point.

The code shown at the bottom compilers and runt correctly, but some relations (`/*Tree_tag,*/` and `/*Parasite_tag*/`) are commented out. If uncommented, MSVS2017 shows

```
error C2664: 'void Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>,std::tuple<>>::removeParent(const Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree_tag,Dog_tag>> *const )': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Dog_tag>> *' to 'const Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree_tag,Dog_tag>> *const '
note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

and G++ shows

```
In instantiation of ‘void Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<_El0, _El ...> ::removeAllChildren() [with TChildTag = Dog_tag; TChildTags = {}]’:
Main.cpp:126:1:   required from here
Main.cpp:73:43: error: invalid conversion from ‘Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Dog_tag> >*’ to ‘const TParent* {aka const Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag> >*}’ [-fpermissive]
    for (auto&& child : childrenPtrs) child->removeParent(this);
```

The problem is with the `this` type qualifiers. Because I iteratively strip off template arguments with for instance

```
class Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTag, TChildTags...>>
: public Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
```

the resulting `this` of the base type does not match the original type. Like the error shows: the original type of `Human` = `Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Tree_tag,Dog_tag>>`. However, due to the iterative stripping, the type of `this` in the base is `Obj<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<Dog_tag>>`.

I tried to use `reinterpret_cast` as suggested:

```
template<typename T>
void addParent(T* const parentPtr) {
    parentsPtrs.push_back(reinterpret_cast<TParent* const>(parentPtr));
}
template<typename T>
void removeParent(T const* const parentPtr) {
    auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs),
        reinterpret_cast<TParent const* const>(parentPtr));
    if (it != std::cend(parentsPtrs)) parentsPtrs.erase(it);
}
```

But then the problem is that **everything** is cast to an allowed parameter. I.e. this code works:

```
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Parasite p1;
    addRelation(&h1, &p1);
}
```

...Which should not be possible, as `Human` and `Parasite` are not related directly.

So how can I correctly keep the `this` type qualifiers of the top (most derivative) class, complying to `Human`, `Dog`, etc types?

Working code(with comments):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using prtVector = std::vector<T*>;

class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const = 0;
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const = 0;
    virtual void removeAllParents() = 0;
    virtual void removeAllChildren() = 0;
};

template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename TParentTag, typename... TParentTags, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<std::tuple<TParentTag, TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    using TParent = typename TParentTag::obj_type;
    prtVector<TParent> parentsPtrs;
public:
    void addParent(TParent* const parentPtr) { parentsPtrs.push_back(parentPtr); }
    void removeParent(TParent const* const parentPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs), parentPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(parentsPtrs)) parentsPtrs.erase(it);
    }

    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        auto result = Obj<std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllParents();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return Obj<std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {
        Obj<std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllParents();
        for (auto&& parent : parentsPtrs) parent->removeChild(this);
    }
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
    }
};

template<typename TChildTag, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTag, TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    using TChild = typename TChildTag::obj_type;
    prtVector<TChild> childrenPtrs;
public:
    void addChild(TChild* const childPtr) { childrenPtrs.push_back(childPtr); }
    void removeChild(TChild const* const childPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs), childPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(childrenPtrs)) childrenPtrs.erase(it);
    }

    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        auto result = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
        for (auto&& child : childrenPtrs) child->removeParent(this);
    }
};

template<>
class Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>> : public BaseObject {
public:
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {}
};

struct Human_tag;
struct Tree_tag;
struct Dog_tag;
struct Parasite_tag;

using Human = Obj<std::tuple<>, std::tuple</*Tree_tag,*/ Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple</*Parasite_tag*/>>;
using Parasite = Obj<std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;

struct Human_tag { using obj_type = Human; };
struct Tree_tag { using obj_type = Tree; };
struct Dog_tag { using obj_type = Dog; };
struct Parasite_tag { using obj_type = Parasite; };

template<class A, class B>
void addRelation(A* a, B* b)
{
    a->addChild(b);
    b->addParent(a);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Dog d1, d2;

    addRelation(&h1, &d1);
    addRelation(&h1, &d2);
    auto result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 2
    d1.removeAllParents();
    result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 1

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++17, you may do (without cast):

```
template<typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename... ParentTags,
         typename... ChildTags>
class Obj<std::tuple<ParentTags...>, std::tuple<ChildTags...>> : public BaseObject
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<typename ParentTags::obj_type*>...> parents;
    std::tuple<std::vector<typename ChildTags::obj_type*>...> children;

public:

    template <typename T>
    void addParent(T* parent) { std::get<std::vector<T*>>(parents).push_back(parent); }

    template <typename T>
    void removeParent(const T* parent) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T*>>(parents);
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), parent);
        if (it != std::cend(v)) { v.erase(it); }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void addChild(T* child) { std::get<std::vector<T*>>(children).push_back(child); }

    template <typename T>
    void removeChild(const T* child) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T*>>(children);
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), child);
        if (it != std::cend(v)) { v.erase(it); }
    }

    std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllParents() const override {
        std::vector<BaseObject*> res;

        std::apply([&](auto&... v){ (res.insert(res.end(), v.begin(), v.end()), ...); },
                   parents);
        return res;
    }
    std::vector<BaseObject*> getAllChildren() const override {
        std::vector<BaseObject*> res;

        std::apply([&](auto&... v){ (res.insert(res.end(), v.begin(), v.end()), ...); },
                   children);
        return res;
    }

    void removeAllParents() override {
        std::apply(
            [this](auto&... v)
            {
                [[maybe_unused]] auto clean = [this](auto& v) {
                    for (auto* parent : v) {
                        parent->removeChild(this);
                    }
                    v.clear();
                };
                (clean(v), ...);
            },
            parents);
    }

    void removeAllChildren() override {
        std::apply(
            [this](auto&... v)
            {
                [[maybe_unused]] auto clean = [this](auto& v) {
                    for (auto* child : v) {
                        child->removeParent(this);
                    }
                    v.clear();
                };
                ( clean(v), ...);
            },
            children);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/670914821562e8ea)

With C++14, it would be more verbose to replace the "for_each_tuple" done with `std::apply` and folding expression.

and in C++11, even more with `std::get<T>(tuple)`.

Comment: Wow, very nice, this way no casting is required. thank you. [I was trying this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161645/conflictions-declaration-redefinition-different-basic-types), but since I'm not familiar with things like `std::get<std::vector<T*>>(parents)` and `std::apply` (and did not find any posts suggesting their use) I couldn't get it to work. Hence my solution below.

Comment: Btw, I think you need the `OwnTag`, else you might have problem with `using Tree = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>; using House = Obj<std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;` (`House` and `Tree` would be the same object).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've thought a lot about this, and decided to add the original type as another template argument.
So the class signature will be something like:

```
template<typename TOwnTag, typename TParentTag, typename... TParentTags, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTag, TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    using TOwn = typename TOwnTag::obj_type;
```

This seems to fix my issue, as I can now use

```
reinterpret_cast<TOwn* const>(this)
```

The complete working code then becomes:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
using prtVector = std::vector<T*>;

class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const = 0;
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const = 0;
    virtual void removeAllParents() = 0;
    virtual void removeAllChildren() = 0;
};

template<typename TOwnTag, typename TParentTuple, typename TChilderenTuple>
class Obj;

template<typename TOwnTag, typename TParentTag, typename... TParentTags, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTag, TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    using TOwn = typename TOwnTag::obj_type;
    using TParent = typename TParentTag::obj_type;
    prtVector<TParent> parentsPtrs;
public:
    //prevent base function hiding
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::addParent;
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeParent;

    void addParent(TParent* const parentPtr) { parentsPtrs.push_back(parentPtr); }
    void removeParent(TParent const* const parentPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs), parentPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(parentsPtrs)) parentsPtrs.erase(it);
    }

    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        auto result = Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllParents();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(parentsPtrs), std::cend(parentsPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllParents();
        for (auto&& parent : parentsPtrs) parent->removeChild(reinterpret_cast<TOwn* const>(this));
    }
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<TParentTags...>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
    }
};

template<typename TOwnTag, typename TChildTag, typename... TChildTags>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTag, TChildTags...>>
    : public Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>
{
    using TOwn = typename TOwnTag::obj_type;
    using TChild = typename TChildTag::obj_type;
    prtVector<TChild> childrenPtrs;
public:
    void addParent() {}
    void removeParent() {}
    //prevent base function hiding
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::addChild;
    using Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeChild;

    void addChild(TChild* const childPtr) { childrenPtrs.push_back(childPtr); }
    void removeChild(TChild const* const childPtr) {
        auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs), childPtr);
        if (it != std::cend(childrenPtrs)) childrenPtrs.erase(it);
    }

    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllParents();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        auto result = Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::getAllChildren();
        result.insert(std::begin(result), std::cbegin(childrenPtrs), std::cend(childrenPtrs));
        return result;
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {
        Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TChildTags...>>::removeAllChildren();
        for (auto&& child : childrenPtrs) child->removeParent(reinterpret_cast<TOwn* const>(this));
    }
};

template<typename TOwnTag>
class Obj<TOwnTag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>> : public BaseObject {
public:
    void addChild() {}
    void removeChild() {}
    void addParent() {}
    void removeParent() {}
    //
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllParents() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual prtVector<BaseObject> getAllChildren() const override {
        return prtVector<BaseObject>();
    }
    virtual void removeAllParents() override {}
    virtual void removeAllChildren() override {}
};

struct Human_tag;
struct Tree_tag;
struct Dog_tag;
struct Parasite_tag;

using Human = Obj<Human_tag, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Tree_tag, Dog_tag>>;
using Tree = Obj<Tree_tag, std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<>>;
using Dog = Obj<Dog_tag, std::tuple<Human_tag>, std::tuple<Parasite_tag>>;
using Parasite = Obj<Parasite_tag, std::tuple<Dog_tag>, std::tuple<>>;

struct Human_tag { using obj_type = Human; };
struct Tree_tag { using obj_type = Tree; };
struct Dog_tag { using obj_type = Dog; };
struct Parasite_tag { using obj_type = Parasite; };

template<class A, class B>
void addRelation(A* const a, B* const b)
{
    a->addChild(b);
    b->addParent(a);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Human h1;
    Dog d1, d2;
    //Parasite p1;

    addRelation(&h1, &d1);
    addRelation(&h1, &d2);
    //addRelation(&h1, &p1); // compiler error
    auto result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 2
    d1.removeAllParents();
    result = h1.getAllChildren();
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n"; //print 1

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eWVXrEX8wkrUYiXg)